# Can SIFT match buildings with same texture more accurately than SURF?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift, surf

I tried to match several images containing buildings using SIFT & SURF. The results I obtained were that SIFT was more accurate 
and gave a true match. By contrast SURF did not give me any match.  I think the reason is that the building tiles/textures are the same.
Can someone explain these results when it is generally said that SURF approximately equals SIFT in accuracy ?

Here's the test results:

[SIFT demo code by David Lowe 2005 VS SURF from IPOL by Edouard Oyallon, Julien Rabin](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6OYGZ_DxzJeajdjdVVGTkY0SVk&authuser=0)

I have another test but I cannot create more than 2 links.
Also how would one recognize if the two images are matched?

Comment: Can you show your pictures where accuracy differs most of all?

Comment: I provide  the link above with look at name some start with sift and some with SURF

Comment: SIFT and SURF have a lot of parameters which can affect result. Are you sure you used similar parameter set for 1st and 2nd approach?

Comment: for sift it's David Lowe executable with it's default parameter .
also the SURF default parameter by Edouard Oyallon  .  I convert the Images to gray scale by ImageMagick tool .

Comment: I am not sure it is the best way to use default parameters for software taken from different sources. It is worth to understand every parameter meaning to be able change it according to  you dataset.

Comment: have you ever  try recognition building or texture Image based objects?